# Magento 2 How to change currency symbol position left to right

Tags: price, currency, magento2.2.3

How to display price currency symbol after the amount on the right side.
from: USD333
to: 333USD

Comment: I hope my answer will solve your issue

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by writing single `event observer`

**Create registration file:**

> Vendor\Module\registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Create module file:**

> Vendor\Module\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>        
</config>
```

**Create event File:**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\ChangeCurrencyPosition" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Create observer File:**

Write a `observer` file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Observer` with the file name `ChangeCurrencyPosition.php`

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Observer;    
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    
class ChangeCurrencyPosition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {    
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();    
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);  
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

Run Command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: It did not work, Magento 2.2.3 and base currency is AED not USD

Comment: @AhmadDarwish what error you got after doing same?

Comment: No errors, nothing changing, where to trace the errors any log?

Comment: check error in var/log @AhmadDarwish

Comment: I can see in exception.log : the Item (Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor) with the same ID \"704\" already exists. at /var/www/html/herara/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:404)

Comment: @AhmadDarwish I have solve issue and update code, issue is i miss `Model` folder name in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78671/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-ahmad-darwish).

Comment: @NikunjVadariya, This code is working fine, but I need to add one space after price then need to show symbol

Comment: Thanks. Works in 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

works in 2.4.2

`-- app/code/Vendor/Module |-- etc |   |-- events.xml |`   -- module.xml
|-- Model
|   `-- Observer |`       -- ChangeCurrencyPosition.php
`-- registration.php

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Currency" />

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Currency.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
{
    public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
    {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="change_currency_position" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\ChangeCurrencyPosition" />
    </event>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**ChangeCurrencyPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCurrencyPosition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);
        //$currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);
        return $this;
    }
}
```